# Swap a certain percentage of elements in an array using numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I have created a numpy array with the dimension 2 and shape (43, 64). The array is made up of 2s, 3s, 4s, and 5s. For each column of the array, I now want to swap 5% of all 3s and make the 4s, and similarly, swap 5% of all 5s to make them 2s. Is there a possibility to do this?

I have found solutions to swapping all 3s with 4s and all 5s to 2s as well as solutions to swapping the first and last element of the array. However, I have no starting point for swapping a percentage of the elements.

I initialize my array with the desired dimensions:

```py
import numpy as np

array = np.zeros((43, 64))
```

I then create a loop to make my desired array, which results to be:

```
[[2. 2. 2. ... 3. 5. 5.]
 [5. 5. 3. ... 2. 5. 5.]
 [4. 2. 4. ... 2. 3. 4.]
 ...
 [2. 5. 4. ... 3. 5. 5.]
 [4. 2. 3. ... 3. 5. 2.]
 [3. 3. 2. ... 3. 3. 4.]]
```

Now I want to select each column and exchange a percentage of 3s with 4s and 5s with 2s, but don't know how to approach this.

I expect an output array, with the same dimension as before, just a certain number of values swapped as illustrated.

Comment: Where is the desired output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this is what you are looking for:

```
def swap(array, n):
    indices = [i for i, x in enumerate(array) if x == n]
    for i in indices[:round(len(indices)/20)]:
        array[i] = 7-array[i]
```

You could easily change the code to work for pairs as well, so already swapped elements are not considered:

```
def swap(array, a, b):
    a_i = [i for i, x in enumerate(array) if x == a]
    b_i = [i for i, x in enumerate(array) if x == b]
    for i in a_i[:round(len(a_i)/20)]:
        array[i] = b
    for i in b_i[:round(len(b_i)/20)]:
        array[i] = a
```

This example changes only the first 5% of the elements (rounded). If you want those elements to be picked at random you could change the for loops so they do so.